# Programmatically reference an array of another schema in Mongoose and save to JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I´m building a script to automatically build my mongoose schemas from data definition files. At a certain point I need to define programmatically a type as being an array of another type.

In my JavaScript code, I´m using:

**PropertySchema.js**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const PropertySchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name: {
        type: String
    },
    description: {
        type: String
    },
    value: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed
    },
 });

export default PropertySchema;
```

The javsacript builder to build schemas.

**schemaBuilder.js**

```
import PropertySchema from './PropertySchema';

let schema = {};

schema.name = {
   type: "String"
   unique: true
   required: true
}

schema.props = {
   type: [PropertyArray]  <=== Error on runtime
}

schema.createdAt = {
   type: "Number"
}

fs.writeFile(".", JSON.stringify(schema), "schema.json");
```

And finally `MyModel.js`:

```
import schema from './schema.json';

const myschema = new mongoose.Schema(myschema);

export default mongoose.model('MyModel', myschema);
```

The program runs fine and the `schema.json` file is generated. When I run `MyModel` on mongoose I´m getting the following error:

```
   throw new TypeError('Undefined type `' + name + '` at `' + path +
    ^

TypeError: Undefined type `undefined` at `obj.deleted.required`
  Did you try nesting Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays.
```

How can I programmatically define an array of another schema as below, as save it to a JSON file ?

```
   type: [PropertyArray]
```

Comment: You just want to refer to another collection? Use *ref* as shown [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html). I'm a bit confused by the writing to JSON stuff, so I'm not 100% sure if that is what's you are asking for.

Comment: Yes, my confusion is putting that on a JSON for later reading, so I would though of: `{ type: Schema.Types.Array, ref: "Property" }` but there is no `Schema.Types.Array`...

Comment: I'd try `[{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Property' }]` instead. The array should contain objectids.